# has_many through:, polymorphic, and self-reference

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, polymorphic-associations

I have a tagging system with three models: `Person (People)`, `Tag`, and `Tagging`.

I want to be able to tag both Person and Tags (so tag the tags)

The models for the `Person` and `Tagging` seem to be correct:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base

 #associations
 has_many :taggings, as: :taggable
 has_many :tags, through: :taggings

end


class Tagging < ActiveRecord::Base

 attr_accessible :taggable_id, :taggable_type

 #associations
  belongs_to :tag
  belongs_to :taggable, polymorphic: true

 end
```

So I am able to do `<Person_instance>.tags` and get the correct tags.

The problem comes with Tags. I tried the following:

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name

  has_many :taggings
  has_many :tags, through: :taggings, source: :taggable, source_type: :'Tag'

  has_many :people, through: :taggings, source: :taggable, source_type: :'Person'

end
```

With this setup, the tags are still able to tag other tags, but the model flips which one is tagged. For example, if I am searching for the tags for Tag.id == 10, then the SQL should search for taggable_id = 10, NOT on tag_id as below:

```
Tag.find(10).tags
Tag Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `tags`.* FROM `tags` WHERE `tags`.`id` = 10 LIMIT 1
Tag Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `tags`.* FROM `tags` INNER JOIN 
 `taggings` ON `tags`.`id` = `taggings`.`taggable_id` 
  WHERE `taggings`.`tag_id` = 10 AND `taggings`.`taggable_type` = 'Tag'
```

This works correctly for Person, where the SQL searches for `taggable_id` :

```
Person.find(:last).tags
Person Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `people`.* FROM `people` ORDER BY `people`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
Tag Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `tags`.* FROM `tags` INNER JOIN `taggings` ON 
 `tags`.`id` = `taggings`.`tag_id` WHERE `taggings`.`taggable_id` = 3 
 AND   `taggings`.`taggable_type` = 'Person'
```

Ideas on how I can tag tags would be appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: taggable is not defined in the tag model. Have you tried has_many :taggings AND has_many :taggings, as: :taggable ?